# Bind event on body but not current element, then unbind it inside of the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the `tr` to an `input` on `doubleclick`, let the user edit it, then when they click outside the box, i call a function to update the db and restore the table row, and unbind the event. of course, it doesn't work as expected.

```
var edit_event;
$('.editable-column').on('dblclick',function(e){
    //make editable
    var type = $(this).data('type'),
    val = $(this).text(),
    id= $(this).parents('tr').data('id'),
    column = $(this).data('column'),
    model = $(this).parents('table').data('model');
    if(type == 'textarea'){
        $(this).html('<textarea data-id="'+id+'" data-model="'+model+'" data-column="'+column+'" class="editing" style="min-height: 80px;">'+val+'</textarea>');
    }
    if(type == 'input'){
        $(this).html('<input data-id="'+id+'" data-model="'+model+'" data-column="'+column+'" class="editing" type="text" value="'+val+'" />');
    }
    edit_event = $('body').not(this)[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        //save model
        var $el = $('.editing');
        var id= $el.data('id'),
        column = $el.data('column'),
        model = $el.data('model'),
        val = $el.val();
        $el.parent('td').html( val );
        updateModel(model,id,column,val);
        $('body')[0].removeEventListener('click',edit_event);
        edit_event = null;
    });
});
```

**Adding some html to clear up the picture**

```
<table data-model="video">
    <tbody>
        {% for item in pending_videos %}
        <tr data-id="{{item.id}}" data-type="{{item.type}}" data-file="{{item.video_file}}">
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <button type="button" class="preview-vid btn btn-md btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#preview-window" >
                    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="approve-vid btn btn-md btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="delete-vid btn btn-md btn-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="editable-column" data-type="input">{{item.title}}</td>
            <td class="editable-column" data-type="textarea">{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.upload_date|date('m/d/Y')}}</td>
            <td>
                <select class="cat-opts select-onload video-category" data-selected="{{item.videocategory_id}}" autocomplete="off">
                {{category_options|raw}}
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after discussing it with a friend, i was able to see a much simpler solution.

Instead of attempting to listen for a second event on the body, i just focus the input and bind to its `blur` event.

```
$('.editable-column').on('dblclick',function(e){
    //make editable
    var type = $(this).data('type'),
    val = $(this).text(),
    id= $(this).parents('tr').data('id'),
    column = $(this).data('column'),
    model = $(this).parents('table').data('model');
    if(type == 'textarea'){
        $(this).html('<textarea data-id="'+id+'" data-model="'+model+'" data-column="'+column+'" class="editing" style="min-height: 80px;">'+val+'</textarea>');
    }
    if(type == 'input'){
        $(this).html('<input data-id="'+id+'" data-model="'+model+'" data-column="'+column+'" class="editing" type="text" value="'+val+'" />');
    }

    //focus input then listen for blur
    $(this).children(':input').focus().blur(function(){
        //save model
        var $el = $('.editing');
        var id= $el.data('id'),
        column = $el.data('column'),
        model = $el.data('model'),
        val = $el.val();
        $el.parent('td').html( val );
        updateModel(model,id,column,val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Without seeing any working sample (HTML markup???) this is quite unreadable code... And this is more true than you post a question/answer, and I don't see how this could be helpful for any other reader

Comment: @A.Wolff its a table. doesn't require much imagination to see what this code does (IMO)

Comment: At least provide minimalistic sample replicating issue, not all this unrelevant code. I'm quite sure there is better workaround.

Comment: This code isn't useless. this code allows me to replicate the functionality of the x-editable library in one single callback.

Comment: Sorry, i meant unrelevant part of code regarding your issue, i used useless but edited it, my bad! And as a side note regarding your edited code in question, HTML markup as rendered client side is more helpful than server side code. Ok we can still figure what's going on but...(that's the imagination part i guess...)